# Setting int more than once causes crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, int, nsnumber

I'm doing a CABasicAnimation and getting the value from a nested NSMutableArray.

Everything is great the first time it runs but crashes when called again either with custom functions or viewDidLoad.

I've isolated it down to this line

```
int int1 = [[[locationsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0  ]integerValue] ;
```

I assume it's to do with int not being a pointer but I'm lost as have to get the value without crashing the second time around

```
Process:         CEO Report 2011 [61880]
Path:            /Users/julian/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/03CFB7BC-0722-4CA0-9E7D-39772AEEF444/CEO Report 2011.app/CEO Report 2011
Identifier:      CEO Report 2011
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [252]

Date/Time:       2011-11-13 17:04:28.093 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000005079706f
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: objectAtIndex:
iPhone Simulator 235, iPhone OS 4.2 (iPad/8C134)

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x012f1a78 objc_msgSend + 44
1   CEO Report 2011                 0x0001afbd -[TalentRVC doBoxes:] + 61 (TalentRVC.m:594)
2   CEO Report 2011                 0x00017025 -[TalentRVC locationSelected:] + 1123 (TalentRVC.m:137)
3   CEO Report 2011                 0x0001659f -[TalentRVC segmentedControlIndexChangedA] + 290 (TalentRVC.m:53)
4   UIKit                           0x002fba6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
5   UIKit                           0x0038a1b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
6   UIKit                           0x0038c647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
7   UIKit                           0x0038a16c -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
8   UIKit                           0x003c96b2 -[UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:] + 574
9   UIKit                           0x003ce17e -[UISegmentedControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 971
10  UIKit                           0x00320025 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
11  UIKit                           0x0030137a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
12  UIKit                           0x00306732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
13  GraphicsServices                0x01a5ca36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
14  CoreFoundation                  0x01171064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
15  CoreFoundation                  0x010d16f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
16  CoreFoundation                  0x010ce983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
17  CoreFoundation                  0x010ce240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
18  CoreFoundation                  0x010ce161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
19  GraphicsServices                0x01a5b268 GSEventRunModal + 217
20  GraphicsServices                0x01a5b32d GSEventRun + 115
21  UIKit                           0x0030a42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
22  CEO Report 2011                 0x00002864 main + 102 (main.m:14)
23  CEO Report 2011                 0x000027f5 start + 53

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a10382 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a10a9c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0ff59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0fcfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0f781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0f5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:  WebThread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x989e9afa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x989ea267 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x011714a6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce874 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
6   WebCore                         0x023e1423 RunWebThread(void*) + 499
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a17259 _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a170de thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x989e9afa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x989ea267 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x011714a6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce874 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x010ce161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
6   Foundation                      0x0009b162 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
7   Foundation                      0x00065d4c -[NSThread main] + 81
8   Foundation                      0x00065cd8 __NSThread__main__ + 1387
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a17259 _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a170de thread_start + 34

Thread 4:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a08ac6 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x01102cbc __CFSocketManager + 812
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a17259 _pthread_start + 345
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a170de thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0f412 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0f9a8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x98a0f5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x5079706f  ebx: 0x0001af8c  ecx: 0x04c8a1ff  edx: 0x00200855
  edi: 0x010bfbd0  esi: 0x56e58955  ebp: 0xbfffd408  esp: 0xbfffd3d4
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0x012f1a78   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x5079706f

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x29ffb +CEO Report 2011 ??? (???) <C5838026-29D3-AF1E-8C66-F7F5C18CDDD2> /Users/julian/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/03CFB7BC-0722-4CA0-9E7D-39772AEEF444/CEO Report 2011.app/CEO Report 2011
   0x4a000 -    0x4cff7 +PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib 1760.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C80BE225-06F2-4CB3-BF89-84A1B0FDCDA2> /Developer-3/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib
   0x51000 -   0x212fe7 +Foundation 751.49.0 (compatibility 300.0.0) <DB9A4461-C768-9B7B-E463-4568E3FAA179> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
  0x2ef000 -   0x7fbff3 +UIKit 1400.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <EE783C53-A647-D7F8-62CF-FB3F7DD16C54> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  0xa40000 -   0xc73ff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.600.0 (???) <78926D2F-9A6C-8B48-BD99-72B3373872BD> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
  0xcdc000 -   0xe3affb +CoreData 320.15.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <75D8B19C-E452-CB13-87FA-CBFD44D3A04F> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
  0xeb3000 -   0xefdffb +SystemConfiguration 379.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5A1E5868-7B70-7184-F4F6-B0FC574E49A0> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
  0xf1c000 -  0x100efef +QuartzCore 1.7.0 (compatibility 1.2.0) <FCA6F109-11B7-B38B-4EBF-D5C2CA9D5CE7> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
 0x1079000 -  0x108aff7 +libSystem.dylib 125.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <76CE85FC-AAC8-DE1C-B533-ABCEF8783B8F> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
 0x109d000 -  0x11ecfef +CoreFoundation 550.52.0 (compatibility 150.0.0) <CDA305C1-38E1-514F-0EFB-4B6A58E296D5> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 0x12de000 -  0x13abfe3 +libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FEB8BB90-29E8-F87A-EA47-9395667DA191> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 0x13fd000 -  0x15a3fe7 +libicucore.A.dylib 45.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <05674AB8-3A5A-0D89-79F8-EA0817A32D38> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
 0x160f000 -  0x170efe7 +libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <08B31BB7-E603-0C9A-1D7D-17637EFEDA54> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
 0x1733000 -  0x1741ff7 +libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F91C1567-31B2-CEFD-2D61-1B76C9F89E6A> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
 0x1746000 -  0x188cff7 +CFNetwork 485.12.7 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FCD41C21-04EF-CDBB-84AC-9017DC3BF552> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 0x190a000 -  0x196efeb +Security ??? (???) <1D093A0E-0E15-231C-F11D-0645230EF7A1> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
 0x1996000 -  0x1999ff7 +IOKit 275.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <E244134E-FFD4-D9C4-BF8E-E1235C0C17B7> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
 0x19a1000 -  0x19b7ff7 +libSystem.override.dylib ??? (???) <477EA8CC-61D1-D179-A7B6-2BB7C377600B> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.override.dylib
 0x19c2000 -  0x1a43ffb +libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <BCEA48F2-1BF3-BD41-F3D8-D905806BFA57> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 0x1a55000 -  0x1a65fe3 +GraphicsServices 14.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <BA0B832B-2252-0434-BFD7-99415BEDF76B> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
 0x1a76000 -  0x1c13ff3 +JavaScriptCore 533.17.9 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8B97277F-F677-F9B0-F82F-5E1E608EFA84> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
 0x1c66000 -  0x1d47ffb +ImageIO ??? (???) <6FAE198A-EAC4-9FBF-A922-1DF8200FD269> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
 0x1d71000 -  0x1dbdff3 +AddressBook 30.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <A011434A-1249-3B7D-97EF-08F0AA0EFBB3> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
 0x1de7000 -  0x1f7efe7 +AudioToolbox 296.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C35F6411-41EB-92EC-F0E1-E3328746061D> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
 0x1fd2000 -  0x1fe5fff +SpringBoardServices ??? (???) <AE58FA0A-B824-CF60-3F40-4CEBBFC2F236> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
 0x1ff1000 -  0x2034ffb +AppSupport 29.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1B38F0B4-36BB-5BEB-917A-A5CFBFCEDADA> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
 0x2059000 -  0x20c7fe3 +CoreText ??? (???) <EE0D05CA-772A-9D07-7931-06B948B209D5> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
 0x20f4000 -  0x2136feb +MobileCoreServices 20.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0F2407B2-C515-C6AC-B72B-0BA21568B152> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
 0x2150000 -  0x2231ff7 +WebKit 533.17.9 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C2BA78C7-45EC-54AA-E020-D7FD6ECE06F9> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
 0x22a9000 -  0x3090ffb +WebCore 533.17.9 (compatibility 1.0.0) <D9EEBA8C-F9D4-FAF4-E0BF-58CE7DAAFB96> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
 0x358c000 -  0x363ffe3 +ProofReader 101.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <196C8CFD-C6BA-A5DE-5785-7F6042DC6425> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
 0x3656000 -  0x3659ff7 +libAccessibility.dylib ??? (???) <BFB0EA39-9E6F-026C-0C23-66A12AB3D336> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
 0x3661000 -  0x368fff7 +PrintKit 66.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F171F166-8B5C-FBC7-497E-9DCDEB158348> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
 0x36a3000 -  0x3724fe3 +CoreTelephony 383.8.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <7BEDF930-9CA4-E6A2-BBCE-C6E7A14DEE69> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
 0x3767000 -  0x3768fff +DataMigration ??? (???) <87E44081-5DCB-6597-6865-90780FEB8597> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
 0x376d000 -  0x3770ff7 +MobileInstallation ??? (???) <DFD90490-F485-6945-1ABE-F4D6C7A94574> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
 0x3776000 -  0x37aafff +Bom 157.0.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <7FE61FCF-0E89-0744-F24C-2D1F6C1EAE89> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
 0x37b7000 -  0x37c4fe7 +libbz2.1.0.dylib 1.0.5 (compatibility 1.0.0) <BD82EE16-8FB3-A7F5-4CC0-EDE15AC18507> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
 0x37c9000 -  0x37d4ff7 +AggregateDictionary ??? (???) <37904D52-6186-14BB-560B-D8B21316BB52> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
 0x37df000 -  0x3853ff7 +CoreAudio ??? (???) <0669925D-3993-07DC-9E76-369C1709553E> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
 0x3888000 -  0x3cf8ff3 +libBLAS.dylib ??? (???) <3EE46AD9-7807-F326-E0AF-BAEF5939654B> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 0x3d1e000 -  0x4160fe7 +libLAPACK.dylib ??? (???) <F66279A8-EE9C-5723-C3A0-E507ED462F8F> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
 0x418c000 -  0x4198ff7 +CoreVideo 1.6.1 (compatibility 1.2.0) <966447F0-FB24-EC43-006E-CD32F1924481> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
 0x41a5000 -  0x41b6ff7 +OpenGLES ??? (???) <EC9C05E6-BC78-B1B0-2044-7189D39A06FE> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
 0x41bf000 -  0x41c4ff3 +libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <0694A0A1-F539-2856-C2BA-61D323D56DEF> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
 0x41ca000 -  0x4205ff7 +libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <9318562A-FDB5-0722-FC9C-BA0057BD3F53> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
 0x420e000 -  0x4319ff7 +libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <F7AC6198-8A35-5DC9-2BDD-AD03BEC21EF5> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
 0x4339000 -  0x4340fff +libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <785DDEAB-CB21-E1A6-35C2-A7A3E02E48B2> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
 0x4348000 -  0x4b2ef4f +libLLVMContainer.dylib ??? (???) <067A9A4D-1B73-B338-BD26-54D28AFCC04F> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libLLVMContainer.dylib
 0x4c85000 -  0x4c8aff3 +AssetsLibraryServices ??? (???) <5BC721E0-FB4E-B81B-4FED-DF7189AD8BA0> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
 0x4c90000 -  0x4c90ff7 +libresolv.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <78A807DB-B13E-9550-9C2E-8DA1DCBFEE8A> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libresolv.dylib
 0x4f52000 -  0x4f9ffe7 +libCGFreetype.A.dylib 600.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <2DFF120B-1542-ED85-07DC-EE7394592B76> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
 0x4fb7000 -  0x4fe0fe7 +libRIP.A.dylib 600.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <0E986874-F95E-1CA2-C221-E99DBD2E6AB1> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
 0xbeb0000 -  0xbeb9fff +WebUI ??? (???) <33AE9B5E-6083-2103-174B-2E6EC60A58A6> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
 0xbec3000 -  0xbec7ff3 +CertUI ??? (???) <5C86FEAC-C796-A9EA-076F-5A34B74B755E> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
 0xbece000 -  0xbed4ff3 +libMobileGestalt.dylib ??? (???) <1A9029E7-6BCA-46F5-0FAE-FB96EED30A05> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
 0xbedc000 -  0xbeefffb +PersistentConnection ??? (???) <E7C7258E-A316-B701-08C2-2A58A90211AB> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
 0xc210000 -  0xc26bff7 +ManagedConfiguration ??? (???) <85935272-F391-D5FF-9976-EFC8560AC1CB> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
 0xc2a9000 -  0xc2b7ff3 +AccountSettings ??? (???) <E77F2419-8ADC-3CC5-23A9-74F2CECA68B3> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
 0xc2c1000 -  0xc2c5fff +ApplePushService ??? (???) <218FD678-275F-0EDC-C9FF-D03062736212> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
 0xc2cb000 -  0xc2dcffb +DataDetectorsUI 52.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <A2C9C080-84D0-5B51-40BE-4B6A7C512D91> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
 0xc2e9000 -  0xc2fdfe7 +DataDetectorsCore 154.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <113CA3D9-474B-1223-ACA7-EB4D473C1583> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
 0xcdbd000 -  0xce00ff3 +QuickLook ??? (???) <94F8984E-BCEA-ADED-7749-C29CE5E04C68> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
 0xce29000 -  0xcf75fff +RawCamera 1.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33F076B3-56FC-6978-3FD7-DF5B1A416D02> /Developer-3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4163b  dyld 132.1 (???) <4CDE4F04-0DD6-224E-ACE5-3C06E169A801> /usr/lib/dyld
0x91590000 - 0x91593fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x91681000 - 0x91681ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <3891A689-4F38-FACD-38B2-4BF937DE30CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x92ff7000 - 0x930ebff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <061ABF36-8BA9-79C1-6CE7-EC69A4998F51> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x9352d000 - 0x93541fe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <821E415B-6C42-D359-78FF-E892792F8C52> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x9554f000 - 0x9562ffe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <D029C515-08E1-93A6-3705-DD062A3A672C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x95630000 - 0x9569afe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x97f72000 - 0x97f7eff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x97f7f000 - 0x97f7fff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <FF4DC8B6-0AB0-DEE8-ADA8-7B57645A1F36> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9869b000 - 0x986bbfe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <BF7FF2F6-5FD3-D78F-77BC-9E2CB2A5E309> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x98704000 - 0x98746ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8A4721DE-25C4-C8AA-EA90-9DA7812E3EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x98747000 - 0x987b6ff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <595A5539-9F54-63E6-7AAC-C04E1574B050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x989e9000 - 0x98b90ff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x9a4e5000 - 0x9a542ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

EDIT: After turning on NSZombieEnabled looks like my NSMutableArray is being deallocated?

.h

```
@interface TalentRVC : UIViewController <locationGlobalMenuDelegate, industryGlobalMenuDelegate>{   
    NSMutableArray *locationsArray;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *locationsArray;
@end
```

.m

```
-(void)buildArrays {
    locationsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 8];
    for (int i = 0; i!=8; i++){
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 8];
        [locationsArray addObject: array];
    }

    //Africa
    [[locationsArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 83]];
    ...

    //Middle East
    [[locationsArray objectAtIndex:1] addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 89]];
    ...

    NSLog(@"Built locationsArray");

 }
```

So after running the first time locationsArray is dumped from memory? If so, how do I can it?

Comment: Where is your crash log ? Post it here.

Comment: set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and run your application.

Comment: Ahhhh... " *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6245b90 " Does this mean my NSMutableArray is being released?

Comment: that means you are sending objectAtIndex: method to released array instance.

Comment: Hi Mr 0x8badf00d - yep, just sussed that that's to your Zombie tip, but I'm at a loss to keep the NSMutableArray instance in memory....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
locationsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 8];
```

to this

```
locationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 8];
```

If you are using ARC you are done. If not you have to think about where to release this memory again.

Comment: I just added [locationsArray retain]; which fixed it but now I see your answer is soooooo obvisious.